# flutter: PlatformException(5, Couldn't find product., {code: 5, message: Couldn't find product., underlyingErrorMessage: , userCancelled: false}, null

Tags: flutter, in-app-subscription

I am facing this issue while implementing the in-app subscription in my Flutter app using Revenucat. Here is my code:

```
ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  await Purchases.purchaseProduct('monthly');
                },
                child: const Text('Try fo free'),
              ),
```

Comment: It appears to be error from inside the code inside the function you call , it's very hard to guess with out giving out more code